# How to avoid nuget authentication when pushing package?

Tags: authentication, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-server

while pushing a nuget package to a local feed at `http://localhost/site`, it asks for credentials.

eg: nuget push ‘OracleDataAccess.1.0.0.nupkg’ -s 'http://10.xx.xx.2/SNNuget/mykey'

I am able to browse the feed directly and see the packages that I manually placed there.
Any possibility to disable this? or any other solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Isn't that what the ApiKey is for?

```
nuget push foo.nupkg 33300000-3330-3330-3330-333033303330 -s http://customsource/
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the following Gist can help you? https://gist.github.com/xavierdecoster/3205826

It contains the nuget.exe commands that allow you to store your feed credentials on your development machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can find your Api Key under https://www.nuget.org/account,
it looks like this:
[image]
and you can either pass the **API Key** as a command line argument to `nuget push` or preferably use [`nuget setapikey <key> -source <url> [options]`](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/tools/nuget.exe-cli-reference#setapikey) to bind a server URL with its credentials and never have to worry about it again :)